# Create a Windows Store App Pie Timer or Ellipse clockwise fill or Circular Progress Bar

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-store-apps, expression-blend, blend

I'm trying to create an animation in a Windows Store App pretty much like the following: http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/BHEwo
[image]

From what I search I end up with `RadialGradientBrush` or `Ellipse.OpacityMask` that do not exist in WinRT. I've considered using a PieChart library, however, given the *simplicity* of the animation, I think there must a better way of doing this. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the background a static color or does the animation need to appear above other elements so you can see through it (like would a background be seen through the white part if your example or is it always going to be white?) I like this challenge, if I have time later I'll sort it out.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisW. In my case the Ellipse is white and will be on top of a Background. There is no transparency involved in it's color (besides the clear animation wanted) and it's a solid color.

Comment: Unless someone's already [made that wheel](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-animated-pie-slice.html) though I may be able to come up with a way that is xaml only

Comment: Charles Petzold, Jerry Nixon and me it seems... http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/CountdownControl/CountdownControl.xaml.cs

Comment: I haven't had time to try yet, but I'm still thinking it can be done in just xaml with some imagination and animation, but can't say for sure until I try lol. I saw your comment on there @FilipSkakun and should have just tagged ya on here in the first place. Cheers amigo

Answer (score 0):

I found this link last night that I think is somewhat relevant to your problem.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20648.using-the-rendertargetbitmap-in-windows-store-apps-with-xaml-and-c.aspx

I did a search and found this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip(v=vs.110).aspx

I think the xaml at the bottom might get your in the right direction.

```
  <Image
  Source="sampleImages\Waterlilies.jpg" 
  Width="200" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  <Image.Clip>
    <EllipseGeometry x:Name="MyEllipseGeometry1"
      RadiusX="100"
      RadiusY="75"
      Center="100,75"/>
  </Image.Clip>
  <Image.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <PointAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="MyEllipseGeometry1" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(EllipseGeometry.Center)"
            From="0,0" To="200,150" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
            AutoReverse="True" />
          </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```